# How to calculate the requested area

Tags: geometry, area

I do not reach the correct proportions.

Having no sides with numbers or letters I get many relationships, because I put letters to everything not known.

[image]

Comment: It seems we need some more information.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you have no more data you're out of luck and the question will be closed. If there is more context, please edit the question to include it and we may be able to help.

Comment: **The only thing that is that the figure is a rectangle and the final solution 5.5.
You have not more data (it's a problem of area properties)**

Comment: @gimusi I think that there is enough information already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously,$\triangle EFC$ and $\triangle AFD$ similar triangles so $$\frac { A\left( \overset { \triangle  }{ EFC }  \right)  }{ A\left( \overset { \triangle  }{ AFD }  \right)  } =\frac { { \left( 2m \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ { \left( 3m \right)  }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 4 }{ 9 } $$ anf we get that $$A\left( \overset { \triangle  }{ AFD }  \right) =4.5\Rightarrow A\left( \overset { \triangle  }{ ACD }  \right) =7.5\\ $$
it means

$$A\left( \overset { \triangle  }{ ACD }  \right) =A\left( \overset { \triangle  }{ ABC }  \right) =12\Rightarrow A\left( ABEF \right) =5.5\\
$$ 
[image]

Comment: A ratio of $\frac 49$ implies that the area of triangle $AFD$ would be $4.5$, and not 9

Comment: No, it is correct, check my calculation again

Comment: There are several steps and leaps in logic I don't follow.  I agree that $\triangle EFC$ and $\triangle AFD$ would be similar.  Where do you get that $\overline{EF}~:~\overline{FD}~::~2:3$?

Comment: @JMoravitz, since they have the same altitudes

Comment: @haqnatural, we have that the area of triangle $EFC$ is 2

Comment: @s because AD = 3m and DF and FD are worth 3k and 2k respectively

Comment: @JMoravitz,because the are "neighbourhood triangles"  $$\frac { A\left( \overset { \triangle  }{ ECF }  \right)  }{ A\left( \overset { \triangle  }{ FCD }  \right)  } =\frac { \frac { \left| EF \right| \left| FC \right| \sin { \left( \measuredangle EFC \right)  }  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { \left| FD \right| \left| FC \right| \sin { \left( \pi -\measuredangle EFC \right)  }  }{ 2 }  } =\frac { \left| EF \right|  }{ \left| FD \right|  } $$

Comment: A geogebra simulation shows that the answer should be close to $5.49$ (assuming the answer is unique).

Comment: @ Arnaud Mortier  you can upload the .ggb file here

Comment: @JMoravitz  and since you get to this without trigonometry, you're not supposed to use it

Comment: @Walter I don't think you can do that. But the sides of the rectangle are 3 and 5 and $E=(\frac53, 3)$.

Comment: I got tangled up with the explanation of several of you, apparently there was no agreement at some point above

Comment: @Walter, I believe in the  power of human mind, not to any program, anyway what I've written is correct

Comment: @haqnatural  No virtual friend, I do not say that this bad, I only say that I got involved with the explanations below your explanation, I expected a final answer, for example because you called him that way

Comment: @haqnatural your approach is correct, but you seem to have made an error in step 2, Area of $\triangle AFD$ is 4.5 and not 9. Therefore, $\triangle ACB = \triangle ADC = 7.5$. Thus, area of ABEF is 7.5 - 2 = 5.5.

Comment: thank you all, I already understood

Comment: @user625, Thank you for correction, it was a silly mistake